# Is $\sigma(X_1X_2)\subseteq\sigma(X_1,X_2)$ true?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Given two real valued random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, I think that $\sigma(X_1X_2)\subseteq\sigma(X_1,X_2)$, but I can't prove it.

Here $\sigma(X)$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random variable $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$, i.e. $\sigma(X):=\{X^{-1}(B)\;:\;B\in\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)\}$.

Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the fact that $Y$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$ if and only if there exists a Borel function $f$ such that $Y = f(X)$

Comment: $\sigma(u(X))\subseteq\sigma(X)$ holds for _any_ measurable function $u$ and _any_ random variable (or vector) $X$. This is quite obvious from the definition of $\sigma(X)$.